# Pie chart not showing data correctly

Tags: sapui5

My data model:

```
{
    "UserData": 
    {
        "firstName": "Pieter"
        "history": 
        [
            {
                "clientID": 2,
                "distance": "130"
            },

            {
                "client": 3,
                "distance": "300"
            }

            ,

            {
                "client": 4,
                "distance": "430"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**View**

```
                                        <content>
                        <viz:ui5.Pie>
                            <viz:dataset>
                                <viz:ui5.data.FlattenedDataset
                                    data="{/UserData/clockHistory}">
                                    <viz:dimensions>
                                        <viz:ui5.data.DimensionDefinition
                                            axis="1" name="Client" value="{clientID}">
                                        </viz:ui5.data.DimensionDefinition>
                                    </viz:dimensions>
                                    <viz:measures>
                                        <viz:ui5.data.MeasureDefinition
                                            name="Distance" value="{distance}">
                                        </viz:ui5.data.MeasureDefinition>
                                    </viz:measures>
                                </viz:ui5.data.FlattenedDataset>
                            </viz:dataset>
                        </viz:ui5.Pie>
                    </content>
```

I am expecting three pieces in the pie size depending on the distance values.
However I get a different result:

[image]

If I have multiple items in the array of the same client id, will the pie chart automatically group the clients together and add their distances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your JSON format is somehow not consistent, **client** should be **clientID**, and the binding path for FlattenedDataset should be `{/UserData/history}` instead of `{/UserData/clockHistory}`

```js
{
    "UserData": 
    {
        "firstName": "Pieter"
        "history": 
        [
            {
                "clientID": 2,
                "distance": "130"
            },

            {
                "clientID": 3,
                "distance": "300"
            }

            ,

            {
                "clientID": 4,
                "distance": "430"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Second,  the pie chart will not automatically group the clients together and add their distances for the same clientID.

Please run and check the code snippet for details.

```html
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.viz"></script>

<script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:viz="sap.viz" xmlns="sap.ui.commons" controllerName="my.own.controller" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <layout:VerticalLayout id="vl">
            <layout:content>
                <viz:ui5.Pie id="samplepie">
                    <viz:dataset>
                        <viz:ui5.data.FlattenedDataset data="{/UserData/history}">
                            <viz:dimensions>
                                <viz:ui5.data.DimensionDefinition axis="1" name="Client" value="{clientID}">
                                </viz:ui5.data.DimensionDefinition>
                            </viz:dimensions>
                            <viz:measures>
                                <viz:ui5.data.MeasureDefinition name="Distance" value="{distance}">
                                </viz:ui5.data.MeasureDefinition>
                            </viz:measures>
                        </viz:ui5.data.FlattenedDataset>
                    </viz:dataset>
                </viz:ui5.Pie>
            </layout:content>
        </layout:VerticalLayout>
    </mvc:View>
</script>


<script>
    sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {

        onInit: function() {
            var data = {
                "UserData": {
                    "firstName": "Pieter",
                    "history": [{
                            "clientID": 2,
                            "distance": "130"
                        },

                        {
                            "clientID": 3,
                            "distance": "300"
                        }, {
                            "clientID": 4,
                            "distance": "430"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            };

            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            oModel.setData(data);
            this.getView().byId("samplepie").setModel(oModel);

        }
    });


    var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("myView", {
        viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
    }); // 
    myView.placeAt('content');
</script>


<body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any SAP UI5 grouping class or do I have to the grouping by parsing the JSON file and modify it?

Comment: You have to group your data by yourself.